# Unexpected improvements in model

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, yolo

I have a poor dataset, where of the training data has a single object labelled in the image.

Same for the validation set even though I reserved the best (more general and well labelled) to then select the best weights.

As far as I can tell, it seems that the model learns to identify many objects, sometimes very well and sometimes not, even though there is a single one labelled (but many images will have several of these object kinds)

I am thinking of re-labeling the data with the current model, and retrain it.

I get that once the model learns to distinguish an object to minimize the error with the dataset, it may also learn to identify other objects in the image.

However, I wonder this:

1. Would the process of back-propagation punish this extra detections, when the images contain a single labelled object but the model detects many (including the correct one) ?

Comment: Please, put your _specific question_ in the title. Thanks.